# The use of whatever and whichever

Tags: conjunctions

Which of the following  sentences is correct:

> 1. Whichever  decision  you take I will agree  with you.
> 2. Whatever  decision  you take I will agree with you.

Comment: Hi Mahjabin, you may not realise that English Language & Usage (ELU) is a question and answer site for *linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts*. The best place to ask questions about basic English is at [ELL.se]. For further information about what's expected in a question on our EL&U site, see **[Ask]**.

Answer (score 1):

What to use depends on context. **Whichever** refers to a *definite* number of possible decisions already known to those who talk. **Whatever** refers to an *undefined* number of decisions, some of which may be taken in future, and the speaker expresses his or her trust to the other person in taking a decision, without knowing its details.